# dynamic table of content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a fixed table of content on the page that highlights which elements are visible on the page by adding a class called "active"
My html looks like this:

```
<div id="table_of_content">
<a class="essay_intro" href="#">Intro</a>
<a class="essay_body" href="#">Body</a>
<a class="essay_conclusion" href="#">Conclusion</a>
</div>

<div class="dircontent" id="essay_intro">
</div>
<div class="dircontent" id="essay_body">
</div>
<div class="dircontent" id="essay_conclusion">
</div>
```

My javascript looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.dircontent').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
            var id_of_object = this.id;

            if( bottom_of_window > top_of_object && top_of_window < bottom_of_object){
                $("."+id_of_object).attr('class', 'active');
            }else{
                $("."+id_of_object).removeClass('active');
            }
        }); 
})});
```

Currently, the code is triggered once I start scrolling and never goes away. Class active never gets removed from the element that is not visible on the page. How can I fix this? any better solution than this one to show user where they are on the page? I am looking for a simple code than a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
$("."+id_of_object).attr('class', 'active');
```

with

```
$("."+id_of_object).addClass('active');
```

You are removing the class `id_of_object` when using `attr`, so `$("."+id_of_object)` won't find your object anymore.

Comment: Yes this worked. Unlike the first answer. One problem that occurred to me now is that more than one element is highlighted if more than one is visible.. is there anyway that I can make it where only one element is highlighted?

Comment: Try adding `return false;` to the if clause after you use `addClass`. This will terminate the each loop after it highlights one element.

Comment: Yeah, use `return false;`, but also add `$(".active").removeClass("active");` to the top of the scroll function so the class gets removed from other elements. This will make the object that is highest on the DOM (first in the array  `$('.dircontent')`)  to have the class. In this case you can remove your `else` clause.

Comment: Thank you both for your solution.. both of them work. Austin solution is better for me because i use the class "active" on other things on the web page which will make me rename some of them or rename active in this code to something else

Answer (score 1):

jQuery comes with the function `.addClass("classname")`, so use that instead of `.attr()` when dealing with classes. Also, before your each loop, put in:

```
$(".active").removeClass("active");
```

Then just remove your else clause from the if statement. And in your if statement, use:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

You're using classes, so jQuery will select all classes with that name, so anytime you ran `$("."+id_of_object).removeClass("active");` any element with the same class name would have it's active class removed.

Comment: '$(this).addClass("active");' or '$("."+id_of_object).addClass("active");' ? I am trying to add class 'active' to every class that has the same name as the visible id element.

Comment: `$(this)` will work. You're running an each loop on all of them, so you'd hit all of them anyways. Using the `$("."+id_of_object)` would work, but it's easier to read using `$(this)` because it accomplishes the same thing and states you're referring the current iteration in the loop, not some other element.

Comment: `this` does not refer to the element OP wants to add the class to. It is one of the `div` elements. He wants to add the class to the corresponding `a` element in his HTML. `$(this)` will not work.

Comment: Right, right. Yeah, use `$("."+id_of_object)`. This is what happens when I skim code. The rest of what I said still applies.